# How to get message from assertion failure?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting this in the debug console:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794`

but no message about what the assertion failure was.  Other times when I've gotten assertion failures there's some kind of helpful message following it, like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception..." or something.  What's a good way to debug this?

Comment: The very next line should say exactly what the bad assertion was.

Comment: that's what i'd expect, but I get nothing.

Comment: Then what is the next line you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular assertion (which you can find by searching for "UIView.m:8794") deals with Auto Layout.

It looks like you have a UITableView that's involved with Auto Layout. The assertion you're seeing is:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:],
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. 
UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

Perhaps you're trying to use Auto Layout in a UITableViewCell or in the table header or footer views?

Comment: nope not in the cells or header/footer.  but I am getting an ambiguous layout on the table view.  Just trying to add a subview that uses auto layout to a table view but it keeps crashing.

Comment: Auto Layout in tableHeaderView can cause this crash too!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. The table view and everything works perfectly on iOS 8 but crashes on iOS 7.

Turns out, I am setting up my `tableHeaderView` using Auto Layout during `viewDidLoad`.

I fixed this by setting a frame for my `tableHeaderView` instead of using Auto Layout.

As Dave DeLong said, it might also be that you're setting your table view header or footer using Auto Layout.